# How to get average from given values

Tags: java, average

How do I average?. I am suppose to find the average of the `GPA`, total of students, and the total of `GPA`.
example:

**input**:
    4
    4
    4
    4

**output:**
*Total Students*:4

*Total GPA*:16

*Average GPA:* 4

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double GPA = 0, total = 0, average;

        System.out.println("Enter GPA");

        while (GPA >= 0) {
            GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
            total = total + GPA;
            count++;
        }

        average = total / count;

        System.out.println("Total students: " + count);
        System.out.println("Total GPA " + total);
        System.out.println("Average GPA " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? What went wrong?

Comment: When the output Total Student  is displayed it has added one more to it. Example input is : 4 4 4 4 -1. "-1" is to end the loop. the output should be "Total student : 4" but it shows "5" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the problem is that you're getting the wrong answer, the reason is this loop:

```
while (GPA >=0)
{
    GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
    total = total + GPA;
    count++;
}
```

Presumably you intend the loop to exit when the user enters a negative number. What's wrong with it is that it will include the negative number in the total and count. You can rewrite the loop like this:

```
GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
while (GPA >=0)
{
    total = total + GPA;
    count++;
    GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

(Other solutions are possible). Later in your code, you will need to guard against the first number being negative. If that happens, `count` will be 0 and you want to avoid dividing by 0 and printing nonsense results.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the input in your loop at this line

```
GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Problem is that, it will get another input and count will be incremented by 1.
So your total will be 5.
You can probably make it in this way

```
while (GPA >=0)
{
    GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (GPA >=0)
    {
       total = total + GPA;
       count++;
    }
    else
       break;
}
```

Comment: Why is it an infinite loop? It will exit when the user enters a negative number. Also, there is no fixed number of students (and there is no need for such).

Comment: OK, you didnt mention that the loop ends with users negative number. So what's exactly your problem here?

Comment: Well, I didn't ask the question. It's clear from the code that the loop ends when a negative number is entered. OP's comment to the question explains the problem.

Comment: or take the input first out of the code first and then in the loop put GPA = keyboard.nextDouble(); after those operations

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the order of your statements in the while loop and your code should work fine.
In this case,your check (whether to add the i/p to the total) will be done after you key in.
Hence,when you key in -1,the you won't enter the while loop and the last value of -1 won't be added.

while (GPA >=0)
{

```
total = total + GPA;
GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
count++;
```

}